# Update of One field with the combination of two other fields

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have a field called `ac_id`, I want to update this field with combination of other two fields, Other two fields are lookup fields.

I am using process builder to update, the formula used for the update is here

`Domicile_Country__c &" "& AIC_Currency__c`
 but it is updating with the record ids, I'm stuck please help me

Answer (score 1):

It will update with `id`'s because you haven't specified which field to be used. Your formula should be something like this: `Domicile_Country__r.Field_Name__c &" "& AIC_Currency__r.Field_Name__c`

Sample example: I tried on my **Dev org** to update `Name` field of `Opportunity` using Process builder. I used this Formula: `[Opportunity].Account.Name  + " " +  [Opportunity].Account.Id`. See below image for reference: [image]

And this is how your **Output** looks:
[image]

Specify the fields which you want instead of just specifying objects.